# CoinEx API Authorization using c#

Tags: c#, authorization, future

I'm trying to authorize to CoinEx API exactly match with Coinex API documents:
https://viabtc.github.io/coinex_api_en_doc/futures/#docsfutures001_http001_general,
but https responds to me :

> {"code":4006,"data":{},"message":"authorization fail"}

```
static string CalculateSHA256Hash(string input)
        {
            using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
                byte[] hashBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(bytes);
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (byte b in hashBytes)
                {
                    builder.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
                }
                return builder.ToString();
            }
        }

public void GetBalance()
        {
            // Input parameters
            string timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString();
            string secretKey = "xxx";
            string accessId = "xxx";

            // Combine parameters and secret_key
            string combinedString = $"timestamp={timestamp}&secret_key={secretKey}";

            // Calculate SHA256 hash
            string sha256Signature = CalculateSHA256Hash(combinedString);

            // Prepare HTTP request with headers
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", sha256Signature);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AccessId", accessId);

                // Send HTTP request (replace the URL with your actual endpoint)
                string apiUrl = "https://api.coinex.com/perpetual/v1/asset/query";
                var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(apiUrl).Result;
                

                // Process the response
            }
        }
```

Please help

Comment: There may be other issues. But the according to the documentation you should not only hash the timestamp and secret key, but also the querry itself. quote: *Paste the secret_key to the end of the above string*